# How to output array value and name

Tags: java

Hey I'm doing this school assignment here and part of it wants me to output the highest and lowest values in an array, but it wants the name of the array as well as the value it is holding be output. I can output the value easily but I don't know how to get the name with it (e.g. "the lowest number is battery electric car at 21"), any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
package package2;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class newOne1 {
    
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
static int [] nineteen = new int[6];  
static int [] twenty = new int[6];  
static String vehicles[ ] = {"Battery Electric Cars" , "Plug-in Hybrid Electric Cars" ,
        "Light goods vehicles (LGVs)" , "Battery Electric LGVs" ,
        "Motorcycles" , "Other "}; 

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    input19();

}

public static void input19() {
    
    int highest=0, lowest=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of registrations in 2019 for the following vehicles; \n");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++) {
        
        System.out.println(vehicles[i]);
        nineteen[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();
    
        if (nineteen[i] > highest) {
            highest = nineteen[i];
        }
    
        if (nineteen[i] < lowest) {
            lowest = nineteen[i];
        }
    
    }
    
    System.out.println("The vehicle with the highest amount of registrations in 2019 is " + highest);
    System.out.println("The vehicle with the lowest amount of registrations in 2019 is " + lowest);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to how you made a variable that would hold the highest and lowest value of the array, make two values that will hold the highest and lowest indices of the vehicles array, and print them at the end. I am practicing my Java through overflow so please respond if this works!

```
    int highest=0, lowest=Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
    int highestIndex=0, lowestIndex = 0;
    
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of registrations in 2019 for the following vehicles; \n");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++) {
        
        System.out.println(vehicles[i]);
        nineteen[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();
    
        if (nineteen[i] > highest) {
            highest = nineteen[i];
            highestIndex = i;
        }
    
        if (nineteen[i] < lowest) {
            lowest = nineteen[i];
            lowestIndex = i;
        }
    
    }
    
    System.out.println("The vehicle with the highest amount of registrations in 2019 is " + highest, highestIndex);
    System.out.println("The vehicle with the lowest amount of registrations in 2019 is " + lowest, lowestIndex);
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for responding so quickly! I've been trying to fit it into my code, but the problem is that the names I need to out print out are Strings so it doesn't out print . Do you know what the work around might be? Thanks Again!

Comment: Well, then do ..., vehicles[highestIndex],... vehicles[lowestIndex]

Comment: OMG thank you so much mate it works now , yeah changing the highestIndex in the print statement to vehicles[highestIndex], worked. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If you dont mind, give my post a like so I can get rep on stack overflow